# Excel Manipulation using Powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have been working with Excel for the past month or so, mainly doing reports for a research project, and recently I realized that I could write a powershell script that can speed up my work.

Example Table:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| text1 | Direction | Origin | Destination | num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 | num6 | num7 | num8 |
+-------+-----------+--------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Test1 | Import    | Place3 | Place1      | x1   | x4   | x7   | x10  | x13  | x16  | x19  | x22  |
+-------+-----------+--------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Test2 | Export    | Place4 | Place2      | x2   | x5   | x8   | x11  | x14  | x17  | x20  | x23  |
+-------+-----------+--------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Test3 | Import    | Place5 | Place1      | x3   | x6   | x9   | x12  | x15  | x18  | x21  | x24  |
+-------+-----------+--------+-------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

So, what I do is that I open a xlsx file, that contains rows filled with package delivery details, seperate imports from exports and then compare Imports with exports and if there are missing desinations (more on that later) I will add the destinations as values and then assign "0" to their individual columns.

Right now I've written the following lines and I don't know where to go from there:

```
# Create Excel Object
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

# Prompt for file path
$Filepath = Read-Host -Prompt 'Where can I find your file? (Path\to\File.xlsx)'

# Open File from inside PowerShell
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($Filepath)

# Use two variables to assign two sheets
$ws1 = $wb.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "sheet1"}
$ws2 = $wb.worksheets | where {$_.name -eq "sheet2"}

# Assign used range to a variable
$mainRng = $ws1.usedRange

# Select Range
$mainRng.Select()

#Find a test value
$ValueSearch = $mainRng.Find("Import")
```

The reason I'm now stuck is because I get `Null` values when I'm selecting a range.

Error Message:

> - $mainRng.Select()
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
>   ```

How can I fix that so I can proceed with my development? Because after that I will loop through every row and, using a conditional, I will seperate `Import` from `Export`.

Comment: Why powershell? Excel has VBA built-in which is likely more efficient and also easier to just start with a button from within the file itself.

Comment: In addition, Excel has a lot of data manipulation capabilities that do not require any programming.

Comment: Powershell seems easier to me and at the end of the day Powershell can access Microsoft's Access, that way I can use one tool to manipulate two. That's why the first thing I asked was exactly that "why PowerShell and not Excel" and the answer was pretty clear "Powershell so I can later solve more complex problems"

Comment: @jkpieterse That's not helpful. We don't know OP's requirements. And the entirety of the VBA Excel API is available to PowerShell, plus all of .NET and other PowerShell cmdlets.

Comment: @LewsTherin Requirements? I just need to split my data to Imports and exports and then fill in the gaps with 0 values (the gaps can be found where `Place1` is not present both as a Destination and Origin, which in lamest terms means that the count of rows/records for Destination and Origin must be equal)

After that I'll try to connect with a Microsoft Access to automatically upload my results.

Comment: Do you need to use the Excel object for what you are looking to do or could you impirt the sheet into a datatable and manipulate it posh?

Comment: I need the excel object for further development, specifically, I need to keep a record of my results for my supervisor

Comment: @LewsTherin I don't see why questioning a chosen technology is unhelpful. It may very well be that the OP is unaware of built-in capabilities of Excel. I expect what he really needs is a couple of PowerQuery queries in Excel. But that depends whether the version he has has PQ available. If not, VBA comes to mind.

Comment: @jkpieterse It's unhelpful for the reasons I mentioned: We didn't know OP's requirements; maybe his/her boss requires a PowerShell script, maybe it needs to be executed from a scheduled task or a DevOps pipeline, the list goes on and on. Also, VBA is an older, less robust technology, and PowerShell is using the same API that VBA would use, so suggesting using VBA in this case does nothing to answer the question asked by OP.

Comment: @LewsTherin Lets agree to disagree. I've seen so many cases where an OP asks a question about using technology A for his goal, being unaware of technology B. I think suggesting other technologies where appropriate can be very useful. Because it is merely a suggestion I posted as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On possible problem is that the Excel file you're processing does not have worksheets with the labels `sheet1` and `sheet2`.

Even if there are no used cells in a worksheet, your code will select the range `A1`.

However if, for example, `sheet2` isn't defined in your worksheet then in your code the variables `$ws2` and `$mainRng` will both be `$null`. PowerShell is actually fine with this but the script will fail at the point that you try to call the `Select` function.

---

Or, as Lews Therin points out in the comments, the filename that you've provided isn't correct.

---

Either way around, the solution is to start checking your variables to see if they're defined so that you can detect these problems earlier and warn the user appropriately. E.g.:

```
if (!$ws1) {
    Write-Host "WorkBook does not contain the worksheet 'sheet2'"
    exit
}
```

Comment: It could be this or that the value in `$Filepath` is wrong. I tested OP's code without any problem calling `Select()`, so either one of these issues seems most likely.

Comment: Great answer. You can check that the `$Filepath` is a valid Windows path by using [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path).

Comment: I do the same work for a lot of files, so I decided to use a prompt each time I wanted to do the report, I mean...c'mon

Comment: Nevertheless thank you for pointing out. I used `$ws1 = $Workbook.Sheets.Item(1)` to fix this issue. It was pretty easy once you mentioned the name was incorrect.